# PHP Relative paths like ASP

Tags: php, include, relative-path

This works

```
<?php include("inc/c.php")?>
```

But in a folder past this, this does not work

```
<?php include("../inc/c.php")?>
```

I have to do

```
<?php include("/var/web/public_html/etc/inc/c.php")?>
```

I know in ASP you can enable virtual paths and directories. Is this the same with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're including a file from a folder, all includes are relative to the includer's file.

Therefore, the same code should work for the file in the sub-folder:

```
<?php include("inc/c.php")?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` to include files relatively to current file:

```
include(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../inc/c.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add directories to PHP's `include_path` directory. When you specify a relative file name, PHP will look for that file relative to all directories specified in the `include_path`.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php#example-488.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
dirname(__file__)
```

it will return you path of current directory.

Answer (score -2):

> But in a folder past this, this does not work

Nope, it **does** work.

> I know in ASP you can enable virtual paths and directories. Is this the same with PHP?

Yes. But whole virtual path thing has nothing to do with your case.

This is not PHP problem. This is developer's problem who is using wrong path.

To make your code fool-proof, always use absolute paths. Build paths not from current location but from the site root. So, it will be all the same in the ANY page on your site.
Most general way would be

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/etc/inc/c.php";
```

Comment: I actually did not down mark this. Despite you being so arrogant as always, you were correct, this error was an issue in code - the paths existed but other PHP was blocking it.